# How to download a specific version of Lens (k8slens)

Tags: kubernetes, installation, makefile

I want to install a previous, specific version of k8slens (https://k8slens.dev/) but impossible for me to find this (neither for mac nor windows !) Do I have to download the source code and rebuild it? Even with this there is no "install" section in the makefile !
Why is it so difficult to find a specific version?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can easily download the source code for a specific version `tag` and the compile and use it. The list of tags is [here](https://github.com/lensapp/lens/tags).

Once you get the source code of your desired version you can generate the binary with :

```
make build
```

And then simply run that binary to get your required version. Just know that `install` simply means copying a compiled binary in a known `Path` of the system so it can be executed. There is nothing special about it.

Comment: This may be the right answer, but for me it was more like
* make build => error; install the right Node version
* make build => error; install Yarn
* make build => error; install the right Python version
* make build => error; install a more specific Node version because the >=14 <15 one installed was not acceptable later in the process
* make build => error; run yarn install
* make build => error; give up—it's not worth it.

Comment: i have the same issue , i have mac , how can i install older lens version ?

Answer (score 1):

The question was made some time ago but just in case you haven't reached the answer yet, One thing I did to solve this problem was that i went to the lens repo : https://github.com/lensapp/lens/releases and search through the old release versions seeking for a binary asset (.exe) (the news version provide the source code but not the binary) then i managed to find the binary of the version 4.2.3.  ( release in Apr 26, 2021)

Worked perfectly for me. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Many guy thinks than Lens doesn't free anymore. But (personal licence) Lens **is  still free**. If you have license problem. you just need
visit https://app.k8slens.dev/subscribe/personal/login and enter credentials, login and the personal license will be added to your lens id.
The issue is with redirection from the Home page when trying to add a new subscription. It redirects you to the download page instead of opening the subscriptions page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install a specific version of Lens for Windows, you can do it with chocolatey:
For example:

```
choco install lens --version=6.0.2
```

You can see which versions are available like this:

```
choco search --exact lens --all
```